# Can I prevent splitting words on a single space in editors like atom, sublime text, and visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, atom-editor, sublimetext

Most text editors for writing code have settings that define which characters break words for things like keystroke navigation and tab-completion. Atom has a `Non Word Characters` field in the settings, Sublime Text has a JSON setting `word_separators`, and Visual Studio Code has a JSON setting `editor.wordSeparators`. There is some variation, but they all default to something similar to this backslash-escaped string

```
"`~!@#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?"
```

None of them appear to include whitespace characters as word separators. This makes complete sense to me, but **is it possible to prevent any of these editors (or an editor I haven't listed) from treating a single space as a word separator?** I want to change this behavior because I have a special case where I'd like to tab-complete strings that contain single spaces.

Comment: Sublime has all sorts of ways to use and modify the autocomplete features. What specifically are you trying to do? This is definitely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I'm not sure how to be more specific than that. Is it possible to tab-complete across single spaces as if they weren't word separators?

Comment: Yes. You can programmatically feed the autocomplete list in a couple different ways, and also use snippets, so that a trigger like `foo bar` will insert one completion, while `foo baz` inserts a different one.